# aiohttp showing 403 Forbidden error but requests.get giving 200 OK response

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using `aiohttp` to asynchronously get download images from different sites using image URL. Before, I used `requests.get` to synchronously do the same. I am able successfully able to download images using `requests.get` but the same URL throws `403 Forbidden` error when I'm trying to download images using aiohttp. I try to find what could be the issue but I haven't got any success so far. `requests.get` doesn't need any extra headers to get the image. The URL is important because that site's URL are getting this 403 error.

The `requests.get` version:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

async def download_image(self, url: str):
    
    ## is_url is just a small function which returns True if url is valid
    if not is_url(url):
        return None

    VALID_MIME_TYPES = {
        "image/jpeg": ".jpeg",
        "image/png": ".png",
        "image/jpg": ".jpg",
        "image/gif": ".gif",
        "image/tiff": ".tiff",
        "image/webp": ".webp",
        "image/apng": ".apng",
        "image/svg+xml": ".svg",
        "application/octet-stream": get_file_extension_from_url(url=url)  
        # get_file_extension_from_url used to get image's type from the URL
    }

    response = requests.get(url)    # Worked successfully and downloads the image
    mimetype = response.headers.get("Content-Type", "").lower()
    
    if mimetype in VALID_MIME_TYPES:
            # creating file name for file
            file_name = f"cimage.{VALID_MIME_TYPES[mimetype]}"
            content = response.content
            
            # converting to BytesIO stream
            return BytesIO(content), file_name, mimetype
    else:
        return None

image_url = "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C15%2C1200%2C600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec"
image_output = download_image(image_url)
```

The `aiohttp` version:

```
import aiohttp, asyncio
from io import BytesIO

async def download_image(self, url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
    """
    Args:
        url (str): image url
        session (aiohttp.ClientSession): Using a common aiohttp session for speedup
    """
    if not is_url(url):
        return None

    VALID_MIME_TYPES = {
        "image/jpeg": ".jpeg",
        "image/png": ".png",
        "image/jpg": ".jpg",
        "image/gif": ".gif",
        "image/tiff": ".tiff",
        "image/webp": ".webp",
        "image/apng": ".apng",
        "image/svg+xml": ".svg",
        "application/octet-stream": get_file_extension_from_url(url=url)
    }
    res = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)

    mimetype = res.headers.get("Content-Type", "").lower()

    if mimetype in VALID_MIME_TYPES:
        file_name = f"cimage.{VALID_MIME_TYPES[mimetype]}"
        content = await res.read()
        return BytesIO(content), file_name, mimetype
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_url = "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C15%2C1200%2C600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec"
    image_urls = [image_url] * 1 # I just increase the number for testing 

    async def main():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
            tasks = []
            for url in image_urls:
                task = asyncio.create_task(download_image(url=url, session=session))
                tasks.append(task)
                
            # returns list of output image in 3 item tuple.
            images = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


    asyncio.run(main())
```

Here's print output of what `res` returns after the aiohttp request is done:

```
<ClientResponse(https://img.evbuc.com/https:%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format,compress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0,15,1200,600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec) [403 Forbidden]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Content-Length': '14', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=5', 'Server': 'imgix', 'x-imgix-id': 'e3fb1d9c2f4cdf79dc45ca6fa20455560bdc05a5', 'x-imgix-proxy-status': '403', 'x-imgix-proxy-reason': '', 'X-Imgix-Render-Farm': '01.140360', 'Date': 'Wed, 18 Oct 2023 20:11:20 GMT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'cross-origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-sjc10076-SJC, cache-bom4734-BOM', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 9e8c29342ff6f7610166562f3559cbe4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'BOM78-P1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'cFMR0YKkz5pLrgzH-IkmYd0JTYqgZPT-wDKbTdxDiOr_ZJH_v3xLeg==', 'Age': '0')>
```

What is the issue in my situation?

I hope I get the solution. Thanks.

Just to be clear this aiohttp code works on other URL but I'm facing this strange issue with this type of URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aiohttp` normalizes the URL (that's not what `requests` does, so the request succeeds). You can disable this behavior using `yarl.URL` with `encoded=True` ([`aiohttp` uses Yarl for URL processing](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/whats_new_1_1.html#yarl-and-url-encoding)):

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import yarl


async def download_image(url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
    """
    Args:
        url (str): image url
        session (aiohttp.ClientSession): Using a common aiohttp session for speedup
    """

    url = yarl.URL(url, encoded=True)
    res = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)

    print(res)
    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_url = "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C15%2C1200%2C600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec"
    image_urls = [image_url] * 1  # I just increase the number for testing

    async def main():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
            tasks = []
            for url in image_urls:
                task = asyncio.create_task(download_image(url=url, session=session))
                tasks.append(task)

            images = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
<ClientResponse(https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C15%2C1200%2C600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Content-Length': '94266', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 20 Sep 2023 13:07:41 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=315360001', 'Server': 'imgix', 'x-imgix-id': 'ec36b5116879ca860a0352578065a6c96481160e', 'X-Imgix-Render-Farm': '01.140360', 'Date': 'Wed, 18 Oct 2023 21:05:54 GMT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'cross-origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-sjc10040-SJC, cache-fra-eddf8230087-FRA', 'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 41b7bdf4fb536a6c72b9f49d9b6affe8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'PRG50-C1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'iYy-EXyB519KYFu_luKo9bAMnMvANxcrHEj6-Sps0LYWJ5cx60Rbvg==', 'Age': '2447892')>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. For solving the issue it works great.